# Cisco 2511 term svr - change baud rate on one reverse telnet connection?

Tags: cisco

I'm not sure this can be done, but figure I'd ask the Gurus here ;)

I have a 2511 router acting as a terminal server for my lab. All the current equipment I have connected to it have serial port baud rates of 9600bps, but now I have a new piece of equipment that has its serial port baud rate set to 115200. For various reasons, i don't want to change this piece of equipment. Is there any way to set the one reverse telnet connection to run at 115200?

Comment: Can you post your current configuration related to your VTY lines?  I believe that, as long as you know which VTY line this equipment was connected to, you could change the speed on that line, but I want to test in my lab first.  And therefore want to replicate your specific config.

Comment: *Not VTY lines... just lines.  My morning coffee is wearing off. :)  For example my 2611 with an NM-16A uses lines 33-48.

Comment: Here is the current config: https://gist.github.com/wdennis/8812452

Comment: Would you mind if I edited the config into your original post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on my testing, you would just have to edit the existing `line` configuration to specify the speed you want on Line 8, for example if that is where you connected your new device.  *I tested this on a Cisco 2611 with the NM-16A async module.*

Existing configuration:

```
line 1 16
 no exec
 exec-timeout 0 0
 password 7 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 login
 transport input all
 stopbits 1
```

Configuration for device on Line 8 to connect at 115200 bps instead of the default 9600 bps:

```
line 1 7
 no exec
 exec-timeout 0 0
 password 7 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 login
 transport input all
 stopbits 1
line 8
 no exec
 exec-timeout 0 0
 password 7 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 login
 transport input all
 speed 115200
 stopbits 1
line 9 16
 no exec
 exec-timeout 0 0
 password 7 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
 login
 transport input all
 stopbits 1
```

Comment: Makes sense! Let me give this a try, and hopefully mark as answered!

Comment: made change, confirmed as correct solution... Thanks!!

Comment: @WillDennis no problem, glad to help!